# How can I search for elements in a parsed XML with Google App Script?

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, xml-parsing

I have the following problem:

- There is a Google Sheet witch contains XML elements (for example: product)
- I want to write a Google App Script for the Google Sheet witch does:

  - parse a XML Document witch is on the Google Drive
  - find out if and how often the elements from the sheet are in the XML
  - write the result in the sheet (witch should be no problem for me)

I can already get the content from the xml:

```
function ReadXml(){
    var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1SNOIXgBpK20jSQ4nl5w2ZPoY9HHnRmAz&export=download").getContentText();
    var xml = XmlService.parse(data);
    var root = xml.getRootElement();
    Logger.log(data);

...
```

Now I am stuck at searching for Elements or get any information at all from the parsed document.

I already tried many different ways to figured it out, with the documentation. At the moment i try this:

...

```
var children = root.getChildren("product");
var product = children[0].getName();
Logger.log(product);
```

}

I know there is one "product" element in the xml, but it seems like it cant find any.

I dont know if I have to work with the XSM or what else is going wrong.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Stack Snippets should only be used for executable HTML/JavaScript/CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The Google App Script XML Service doesn't work without using the correkt namespaces as a parameter.

For my xml i got the namespaces like this:

```
var namespace = XmlService.getNamespace('http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/short');
```

First time working with xml parsing, so I didn't know that. You will find the namespace Link in the first lines of your xml.

After that i could get the information of the elements on the xml:

```
var elementContent = root.getChild("product", namespace).getChild("a001", namespace).getText();
```